# protobuffer throw runtime error as Failed to parse address book in latest current version 3.0.0?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have create a addressbook.proto with this i m good to generate below two files

```
addressbook.pb.h
addressbook.pb.cc
```

with `protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --cpp_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/addressbook.proto`

i have a code which read my address book name readproto.cc

readproto.cc

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
if (argc != 2) {
    cerr << "Usage:  " << argv[0] << " ADDRESS_BOOK_FILE" << endl;
    return -1;
  }


tutorial::AddressBook address_book;

  {
    // Read the existing address book.
    fstream input(argv[1], ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!input) {
      cout << argv[1] << ": File not found.  Creating a new file." << endl;
    } else if (!address_book.ParseFromIstream(&input)) {
      cerr << "Failed to parse address book." << endl;
      return -1;
    }
  }

----
}
```

and i compile as

**c++ readproto.cc addressbook.pb.cc `pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf**

i get executable file nothing bad but my doubt is what file should i load with this executable?

i tired as

```
./a.out addressbook.proto
```

Not sure which file need to load  addressbook.proto is good ??

```
result : Failed to parse address book
```

.

i am new with protobuffer need help on it .Struggling from last three days this my last  hope plss help with in this thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using the [protobuf tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial), Call your program like this:

```
./a.out my_adress_book.bin
```

It will create an empty my_adress_book.bin and then prompt you to add entries.

This part creates an empty file:

```
fstream input(argv[1], ios::in | ios::binary);
if (!input) {
  cout << argv[1] << ": File not found.  Creating a new file." << endl;
} 
....
```

Comment: i have already code below the path from where i am implementing
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial
can you pls let know from this link which bin i need to take as argument?

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial#writing-a-message. You'll run your program like this: ./a.out my_adress_book.bin

Comment: Thank you its working good one last question when my_addres_book.bin is generated??

Comment: I changed my answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the actual binary data.  The data format is defined in the .proto file.  Try to export the data to the file first.  And then read it.

Comment: Can you please show  me with example not able to catch your word pls?

Comment: ofstream file("./serial.data");
address_book.SerializeToOstream(&file);